# Swift_TransportException Connection could not be established with host mywebsite.com

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, smtp, sendmail

Getting the titled issue with a contact form with my site and sending to a SSL email account on a cpanel godaddy server with Laravel. Has anyone has similar?

Here are the credentials im using:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mywebsite.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sending emails natively from your own server similar to `mail()` function use `sendmail` as driver

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=mywebsite.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

OR only use mail

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=mywebsite.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Make sure to clear config cache.

Comment: I now get the issue Swift_TransportException
Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path specified.
] . is this line of code the problem? can you see an error with it?     'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

Comment: @detinu20 try mail driver as `mail` only